# Proper type for multiselect attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, multiselect-attribute

What should be proper type for multiselect attribute? Of course it is connected with adding them programatically.

There is no exceptions while adding `text` type programatically, but you can't use it later in layered navigation.

Is it correct to use `varchar` type?